# Prop with default value gets undefined type in Vue 2

Tags: typescript, vuejs2, undefined, vue-props, vue-options-api

I have a child component with code:

```
export default {
 props: {
  search: {
   type: String,
   default: () => null,
  },
 }
}
```

And a parent component with code:

```
<template>
 <ChildComponent :search="value" />
</template>

<script land="ts">
import ChildComponent from './ChildComponent.vue';

type Data = {
  value: string | null;
};

export default {
 data: Data {
  return {
   value: null,
  }
 }
}
</script>
```

In the parent component IDE underlines 'search' word in the part of code below

```
<ChildComponent :search="value" />
```

and shows an error:

> "Vue: Type string | null is not assignable to type string | undefined"

So prop 'search' has type 'string | undefined' instead of 'string | null'. Why does it happen? I guess search prop is impossible to have undefined value. Even if I'll pass it manually.

Error disappears if I replace 'default: null' with 'required: true'. In this case prop search has type "string", but it doesn't suit me.

Is there a way to avoid this error?

Comment: did you copy this code correctly?  `data: Data { ... }` isn't valid syntax, nor would you type the `data` option of a component to begin with.  I also see you have typos like `land="ts"`.  Are you copying this code to the question by retyping it instead of just copy/pasting?  Not sure how you end up with such mistakes otherwise.

Comment: code has multiple errors that arent related to the question

Comment: sorry for typos. unstead of `data: Data` should be `data(): Data` and there's a typo in word `land` in should be `lang`. I just didn't copy/paste this code. I wrote it right here